# Cant fetch 2 values from other table SQL Query,

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm newbie on SQL, I have 2 simple tables

**ip_track**

| id | current_ip_id | old_ip_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |

And **ip**

| id | ip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8.8.8.8 |
| 2 | 195.19.97.117 |
| 8 | 8.8.4.4 |
| 9 | 1.2.3.4 |

AND I want to get current_ip_id and old_ip_id with its ip in SELECT Statement like

| id | current_ip_id | current_ip | old_ip_id | old_ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 |
| 2 | 2 | 195.19.97.117 | 9 | 1.2.3.4 |
| 3 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 | 8 | 8.8.4.4 |

But if ids are different I got duplicates
For example, for
`SELECT ip_track.id, current_ip_id, ip AS current_ip, old_ip_id, ip AS old_ip FROM ip_track INNER JOIN ip ON current_ip_id = ip.id OR old_ip_id = ip.id`

| id | current_ip_id | current_ip | old_ip_id | old_ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 |
| 2 | 2 | 195.19.97.117 | 9 | 195.19.97.117 |
| 3 | 2 | 1.2.3.4 | 9 | 1.2.3.4 |
| 4 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 | 8 | 8.8.8.8 |
| 5 | 1 | 8.8.4.4 | 8 | 8.8.4.4 |

But expect

| id | current_ip_id | current_ip | old_ip_id | old_ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 |
| 2 | 2 | 195.19.97.117 | 9 | 1.2.3.4 |
| 3 | 1 | 8.8.8.8 | 8 | 8.8.4.4 |

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `ip` table to the `ip_track` table *twice*:

```sql
SELECT
    ipt.id,
    ipt.current_ip_id,
    ip1.ip AS current_ip,
    ipt.old_ip_id,
    ip2.ip AS old_ip
FROM ip_track ipt
LEFT JOIN ip ip1
    ON ip1.id = ipt.current_ip_id
LEFT JOIN ip ip2
    ON ip2.id = ipt.old_ip_id
ORDER BY ipt.id;
```